# Menu Button NavigationDrawer | Hidden ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I state now that I've looked everywhere and I mean everywhere really how to solve the problem I am . In practice I have a navigation Drawer , which uses a toolbar .
This allows navigationdrawer going to open different fragment from the side menu . Now I would like that when cliccasse on the fragment of a map the ActionBar disappear and only appear on the top left of the menu symbol (button menu with the 3 horizontal lines ) . Above the map we say .
I found several apps on playstore they do this thing if I will post a link or a sample photo .

I am at the point of having put in " HIDE" the action bar . Then I would not know how to proceed . Has anyone ever done something like this ? Or you know how to achieve it ?

[image: An Example]